Editing a custom bst file to include urls in references
I have found other similar questions that unfortunately haven't helped me with my issue. I have inherited a modified version of the unsrt.bst bibliography style file, and I cannot get URLs to show in my references.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers,square,comma,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{, }
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./Chapters/FPM_Figures/convertedEPS/}
%\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace} %enables to change the linF1.5e spacing
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\lambdabar}{\mbox{\textipa{\textcrlambda}}}
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast, singlelinecheck=false,textfont=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize}  

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[font={it}]{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma]{natbib}
% \usepackage{bibliography}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.} % change enumerate mode

%#### START DOCUMENT #######################################################################
\begin{document}

\makeatletter\@openrightfalse
\def\@pnumwidth{4em}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}}
\listoffigures

% If you include tables then uncomment the lines below
\newpage
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}}
\listoftables


%#### HEAD PAGE CONFIGURATION ##############################################################
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase \leftmark}}
\rhead{}

%#### MAIN CHAPTERS ######################################################################

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\hyphenpenalty=100000
%\sloppy
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:first}
\input{Chapter1_Introduction/Introduction_v4}
\chapter{Fundamentals of laser-solid interactions}\label{ch:second}
\input{Chapter2_Laser_Plasma_Interactions/theory_v4}
\chapter{X-ray production and interactions with matter}\label{ch:third}
\input{Chapter3_XRays/XRayTheory_v4}

\chapter{Methodology}\label{ch:fourth}
\input{Chapter4_Methods/Methodology_v3}

\chapter{The role of focal spot size and pulse energy in bremsstrahlung and synchrotron production in thick targets}\label{ch:sixth}
\input{Chapter5_GSI/Results2_main_v3}
\chapter{Experimental investigation of the role of focal spot size and pulse energy in bremsstrahlung production in thick targets}\label{ch:seventh}
\input{Chapter5_GSI/Chapter 7_GSI Exp/results3_main_v1}
\chapter{Linear absorption spectrometer characterisation using bremsstrahlung x-rays}\label{ch:fifth}
\input{Chapter6_FPM/Results_main_v5}

\chapter{Conclusions}\label{ch:eigth}
\input{Chapter8_Conclusion/Conclusion_v4}
%#### BIBLIOGRAPHY DEFINITION #############################################################

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{./unsrt_1_doi}

\bibliography{thesisrefs_20240826}


\end{document}

This is the .bst file -- called unsrt_1_doi.bst -- I am currently using:
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
    doi
    url
    urldate
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    { output.state before.all =
        'write$
        { add.period$ " " * write$ }
      if$
    }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

%%FUNCTION {doilink}
%%{ duplicate$ empty$
%%{ pop$ "" }
%%{ doi empty$
%%    { skip$ }
%%    { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
%%
%%  if$
%%}
%%if$
%%}

% FUNCTION {doilink}


%     { doi empty$
%     { url empty$
%   { skip$ }
%         { "\href{" url * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
%         if$
%     }       
%         { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
%       if$
%     }



FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=     %%to put the completed author name change "f." by "ff" 
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #2 + =        %%select number of authors to show
          numnames #1
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " \textit{et~al}." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$

}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
    { ", editors" * }
    { ", editor" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
    { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
        { "--" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
        { "-" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
          while$
        }
      if$
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

% FUNCTION {format.date}
% { year empty$
%     { month empty$
%   { "" }
%   { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
%     month
%   }
%       if$
%     }
%     { month empty$
%   'year
%   { month " " * year * }
%       if$
%     }
%   if$
   
% }

% FUNCTION {format.date}
% { year $empty$
%     { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
%        pop$ "" }
%     'skip$
%    if$
% }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
   


% FUNCTION {format.date}
% { year  "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
%     { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
%        pop$ "" }
%     'skip$
%   if

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ %%title emphasize
  title
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
    'skip$
    { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
    { series field.or.null }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { "number" }
        { "Number" }
      if$
      number tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { " in " * series * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
    { edition "l" change.case$ " edition" * }
    { edition "t" change.case$ " edition" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
% FUNCTION {format.url}
% { url empty$
%    { "" }
%    { new.block " \url{" url * "}" * }
%    if$
% }

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
    { #1 'multiresult := }
    { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
    { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
    { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}



FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
  doilink 
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
    { "chapter" }
    { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
    'skip$
    { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
    { "In " booktitle emphasize * }
    { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Technical Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
    { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
      warning$
      ""
    }
    { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
    'skip$
    { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { series empty$
        { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          "" *
        }
        { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { booktitle empty$
        { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In {\em " booktitle * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  %%format.title emphasize "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { %%journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      journal "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  %%note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
    { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
      organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      organization output
      publisher output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output.nonnull
      address output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
    { address new.block.checka
      address output
    }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
    { organization address new.block.checkb
      organization output
      address output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
    { publisher new.sentence.checka }
    { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
      organization output
    }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

READ

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}


I am aware that the original unsrt bibliography style doesn't deal with urls as it predates the internet. I have tried adding a function to deal with urls that have come from other answers, to no avail.
Here is an example entry for a webpage from my .bib file:
@misc{AlliedVision2024,
author = {{Allied Vision}},
booktitle = {Allied Vision},
pages = {1},
title = {{Manta G-235}},
url = {https://www.alliedvision.com/en/camera-selector/detail/manta/g-235/},
urldate = {2024-07-21},
year = {2024}
}

And this is how this reference is formatted in the final document:

I would ideally like the url and the date accessed in this reference.
Does anyone know what's going on here?
Thanks!

Off-topic: Since you clearly intend to use natbib's facilities, you should delete both instances of  \usepackage{cite}. Do get rid of \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}, but do consider running \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Since you load graphicx, there's no point in loading epstopdf separately. Also, no need for the option pdftex when you load graphicx.  And since you load both caption and subcaption, it's questionable practice to load subfig as well. Finally, nothing good ever comes from loading a package more than once -- cf. amssymb, caption, natbib, and setspace.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, in terms of hacking a modified form of the venerable unsrt bibliography style, I would recommend that you switch to employing the unsrtnat bibliography style, which is natbib's reimplementation of the unsrt style. Happily, unsrtnat is programmed to know what to do when it encounters fields named url and doi.
A minor drawback of this approach is that unsrtnat is not programmed to know what to do with a field called urldate. Fortunately, this is easily remedied by opening your bib file in an editor and doing a global search-and-replace on the string
"urldate = {"

and replacing it with
"note = {Last visited on "

Oh, and please load xurl, not url.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{AlliedVision2024,
  author    = {{Allied Vision}},
  booktitle = {Allied Vision},
  pages     = {1},
  title     = {{Manta G-235}},
  url       = {https://www.alliedvision.com/en/camera-selector/detail/manta/g-235/},
  note      = {Last visited on 2024-07-21},
  year      = {2024}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document} 


Thank you very much for your comments! This has worked for the URLs. Is there a way I can easily truncate my authors to two et al. and only show author initials?

I have figured this out. Thanks for your help!
